# waitpid always returns -1 even if the process is terminated

Tags: c++, macos, qt, process

I'm on Mac and I use Qt 5. I have a button in my QMainWindow that execute a program when the it s clicked.

I used this static function to execute a detached process :QProcess::startDetached (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached).

I have no problem to start / kill a process with this function on Mac.

I would like to determine if the user terminates the process (an OpenGL application). I used this code

```
void MyProgram::startApplication()
{
bool ret = QProcess::startDetached(program,arguments, workingDirectory, &m_PID);
if (ret && m_PID)
{
    printf("m_PID = %d (started)\n", (int)m_PID);
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    connect(thread, &QThread::started, [this]() {
        qint64 pid = m_PID;
        printf("pid = %d (started)\n", (int)pid);
        QThread::msleep(2000);
        while (pid)
        {
            int wstatus = 0;
            pid_t ret = waitpid(pid, &wstatus, WNOHANG);
            if (ret > 0)
            {
                if (WIFSIGNALED(wstatus) || WIFSTOPPED(wstatus) || WIFEXITED(wstatus))
                {
                    // dont kill or stop cuz the process is already finished
                    printf("pid = %d ret = %d (stopped)\n", (int)pid, (int)ret);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (ret < 0)
            {
                printf("pid = %d ret = %d(error)\n", (int)pid, (int)ret);
                //break;
            }
            QThread::msleep(200);
        }
        m_PID = 0;
    });
    }

   bool MyProgram::IsRunning()
   {
       return m_PID != 0;
   }
```

This problem is that waitpid() always returns -1 and I can't never know when the started process is finished or killed.

I think that waitpid works only when you re the parent no in detached process but kill(m_PID, SIGINT) works (stop the process)

I need only to know if the process is finished or not

Answer (score 1):

[QProcess::startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached) documents that:

> Unix: The started process will run in its own session and act like a daemon.

(so I guess it calls [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) or do something equivalent)

If you really want to use [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.html) you'll better use the usual [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/=fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in your own code (but that is not the Qt way of doing).

BTW, why don't you use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) the usual way? It should be more Qt friendly (and more portable to other OSes). You'll use (i.e. connect to some of your [slot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)) the [QProcess::finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) qt-signal.

> but kill(m_PID, SIGINT) works

Of course, [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) can be used on some non-child process.